# Opening frames from emacs-daemon

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon

How do I open a frame at start-up when using `emacs --daemon`? I don't run `emacs --daemon` directly. Instead, I use `emacsclient -c -a ''` which starts an `emacs-server` if there isn't one running already. However, if I simply add something like `(make-frame '((name . "SomeName"))` to `.emacs`, I get an error saying `Unknown terminal type`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your `.emacs` runs when the daemon is started. Usually, you start the daemon without any display system at all, and Emacs doesn't know how to make frames. After `emacsclient` forces Emacs to create a frame in the current session, Emacs then knows how to create frames.

---

You can fix this by using the `--eval` flag of `emacsclient`, which evaluates the lisp *after* Emacs is made aware of your windowing system. In order to create another frame, as you specify, execute this:

```
$ emacsclient -c -a '' --eval "(make-frame '((name . \"SomeName\")))"
```

Which should spawn two frames: the default one, and a new one named "SomeName".

Comment: Emacs will happily create 'frames' in terminals (e.g. try `C-x 5 2`, `C-x 5 o`, `C-x 5 0` in terminal Emacs). IIRC, when the daemon starts, Emacs does not have a terminal at all.

Comment: True. I just realized that, and the functionality is pretty cool. I've amended my answer.

Comment: `C-h i g (elisp) Frames` and `(elisp) Multiple Terminals` are of note here.